"Duplicate choice error" when adding options to a Google Form dropdown, with seemingly unique list
I am running a script where strings are pulled from multiple cells in a Google Sheets page, put into a list, and put in a Google Forms dropdown. A common issue I have run into is the presence of duplicate strings in the list; the item.setChoiceValues(array) function throws this error upon duplicate entries in the array. I have tried many options to remove duplicates in the past, which had always worked. Recently, it has appeared again, and I am 97% sure that the list is free of duplicates this time.
I implemented this code in which an array is turned into a map, where the key is the string in lowercase form, and the value is the normal string. This should seemingly delete any duplicates, as a duplicate key:value pair is replaced in the map by the last iteration of the string. Upon comparing the size of both the new map and the original array, I find that they are the same. This indicates to me that the original array is free of duplicate entries, no matter the string's case. However, I still get the error:
"Exception: Questions cannot have duplicate choice values."
when adding strings to the dropdown.
At this point I am lost. Is there an aspect to an array of strings that item.setChoiceValues() would detect as a duplicate that I am missing?
Image showing the map and original array showing identical size
Image showing the "Exception: Questions cannot have duplicate choice values." error

How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example

I have to apologize for my poor English skill. Unfortunately, I cannot correctly imagine your current script and the input values from your question. Can you provide your current script and your sample values for correctly replicating your current issue Exception: Questions cannot have duplicate choice values.? By the way, are these threads useful for your situation? https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bgoogle-apps-script%5D+%5Bgoogle-forms%5D+Questions+cannot+have+duplicate+choice+values

Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

I am 97% sure that the list is free of duplicates this time. So there is a 3% chance that the list is NOT free of duplicates; in which case, one should not be surprised by this error message. Seriously, please provide sample data and/or troubleshooting data so that we can reproduce your error.

Would you please edit the question to include sample data AND code which will generate the error message. I have tested a number of scenarios and found that the ONLY time that the "Duplicates" error message is generated by item.setChoiceValues() is when the data array contains one or more exact duplicates. For example,  even [James, james, bob, JaMeS, Bob] does NOT generate an error and will populate a LIST item with each of the 5 values. OTOH, [James, james, bob, JaMeS, Bob, James] (note "James": an exact duplicate) does generate the error message.
